# Winforms: Make custom property for UserControl that uses ColorDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm trying to find a way to make a custom property for a UserControl that enables me to use ColorPicker/ColorDialog.

Idea is to have UserControls that's made up of one Panel but make custom BackGround color picker per say

I have no idea if this is even possible? And can't find similar example online

I don't have too much experience with UserControls...

Comment: Define your property **type** to be `Color`?

Comment: Yeah I didn't know it will automatically enable color picker thanks